# Stream camera from iOS app to OSX app

Tags: ios, macos, networking, stream, usb

I would like to use an iOS device as a camera and stream the data to an accompanying OSX app. Wifi is not a valid option and I'm assuming Bluetooth will be too slow, so I'm planning to connect the phone via USB to the Mac.

I've gone through [this networking tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) and have looked at [Apple's EADemo code with EASessionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), etc. but haven't figured out how to put everything together.

When my iOS device is connected via USB to my Mac, it doesn't show up in

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]
```

so I'm kind of lost. Am I going down the wrong path? Any suggestions would be really helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: BlueTooth should be fast enough. The SensorLog app manages to stream sensor data over TCP/IP. That's another option.

Comment: Do it in Swift, not Objective C if you can.